# Is there a way to get the status of an Event Grid trigger for azure function (Complete /Pending or Running)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

by Httptrigger Azure function, if you send a POST request you receive something like this as a response:

```
{
    "id": "66ee5d08196874aeb99c9e62ddc7b190",
    "statusQueryGetUri": "https://asynchttpfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/66ee5d08196945aeb44c9e62ddc7b190?taskHub=Orchestration&connection=Storage&code=FSVfJyGODSeKHPO0cM8Po9e1jMT7MghVMGuJqTaGTN56E1RUHnlVJg==",
    "sendEventPostUri": "https://asynchttpfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/66ee5d08196945aeb44c9e62ddc7b190/raiseEvent/{eventName}?taskHub=Orchestration&connection=Storage&code=FSVfJyGODSeKHPO0cM8Po9e1jMT7MghVMGuJqTaGTN56E1RUHnlVJg==",
    "terminatePostUri": "https://asynchttpfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/66ee5d08196945aeb44c9e62ddc7b190/terminate?reason={text}&taskHub=Orchestration&connection=Storage&code=FSVfJyGODSeKHPO0cM8Po9e1jMT7MghVMGuJqTaGTN56E1RUHnlVJg==",
    "rewindPostUri": "https://asynchttpfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/66ee5d08196945aeb44c9e62ddc7b190/rewind?reason={text}&taskHub=Orchestration&connection=Storage&code=FSVfJyGODSeKHPO0cM8Po9e1jMT7MghVMGuJqTaGTN56E1RUHnlVJg==",
    "purgeHistoryDeleteUri": "https://asynchttpfunction.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/66ee5d08196945aeb44c9e62ddc7b190?taskHub=Orchestration&connection=Storage&code=FSVfJyGODSeKHPO0cM8Po9e1jMT7MghVMGuJqTaGTN56E1RUHnlVJg=="
}
```

The `statusQueryGetUri` provides information of the long running orchestration instance. If you follow this link you will receive a suitable runtimeStatus that describes the status of the orchestration instance along with some other useful information.[here](https://blogs.endjin.com/2019/09/azure-data-factory-long-running-functions/)

My question is now:
actually we don't send a POST request to an Event grid Azure function trigger, Is there any way to get the status of the Azure function? Complete or is still running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure Event Grid is an eventing Pub/Sub model where the interest of source is distributed to the subscribed event handler endpoint or resource in the reliable manner with a retry policy and dead-lettering option. The AEG is waiting for delivery response processing max. 60 seconds.

There is no built-in the features what you are asking in the AEG, however you can use the REST API for metrics of the specific subscription to obtain its counters value:

```
MatchedEventCount,
DeliveryAttemptFailCount,
DeliverySuccessCount,
DroppedEventCount,
DeadLetteredCount
```

The following **GET** is an example for getting a subscription metrics:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/mysubId/resourceGroups/mygroup/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/mytester/providers/Microsoft.EventGrid/eventSubscriptions/mysubscription/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&interval=PT5M&metricnames=MatchedEventCount,DeliveryAttemptFailCount,DeliverySuccessCount,DroppedEventCount,DeadLetteredCount
```

Note, that the authorization header with a bearer token is required for this call.

More details about the monitoring an event message delivery can be found [here](http://Monitor%20Event%20Grid%20message%20delivery).